# Brightness control of secondary display (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: display, brightness

I used the following command

```
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
```

output was

```
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 290mm
XWAYLAND1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190m
```

And then,

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.63
```

It doesn't change the brightness.
These commands worked on previous machine (ubuntu 20.04). Besides the output was not "*XWAYLAND0*" before.

Comment: I hope there will be a solution here. I have tried brightness-controller
I have tried xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.6
I have tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406420/cant-change-brightness-on-version-22-04

Answer (score 0):

same problem with

```
xrandr --output 'XWAYLAND1' --primary --left-of 'XWAYLAND2'
```

It seems as it worked, but displays do not change order.
Also it was working in 20.04.
And also display names changed, as they where 'HDMI-1' and 'LVDS-1' in the previous version.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1244226)