# Can't change brightness on version 22.04

Tags: drivers, brightness, backlight

I'm new to Linux, so I use Linux on dualboot. At the first time of installing Ubuntu, the brightness slider was working fine but when I made some updates + installed an Nvidia driver the slider is not doing anything anymore. Tried adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor` to `/etc/default/grub` but didn't work. Tried to install Brightness Control as a temporary solution but even that wasn't working.
The `/sys/class/backlight` folder has two folder in it; `amdgpu_bl0` and `ideapad`, brightness slider only effect the files included in `ideapad` folder. What should I do?
System specs:
Ryzen 5 4600H
GTX 1650 Ti

Comment: I have a similar issue. From what I read, you may try to revert Nvidia driver to version 470 if you are using 510. Personally I cannot afford it because 470 is not working properly when 2 external monitors are plugged.

Comment: Reverting to old drivers and / or reverting xorg drivers didn't work for me. You may try the answer i posted but if you are not using an iGPU that might not solve you are problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/brightness-control-not-working/15235), I am able to change the screen brightness.
Go to `/etc/grub` and find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` and add `amdgpu.backlight=0` to there. Solved my issue in Fedora and Kubuntu both so the problem is the Radeon Graphics iGPU I guess.

Comment: thank for the advice, sadly I have an intel CPU so it is not going to help for me. Glad you found a solution to your problem!

Comment: Thanks, i hope you can find a solution cuz this thing kills peoples eyes. Good luck!

Comment: milembar, I also have intel CPU and graphics, have you found any other way? the most weird thing is slider is working but buttons are not working

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and the same fix as the accepted answer, but I just wanted to clarify the steps because it was confusing when I tried to follow them.

1). Open `/etc/default/grub` in a text editor with sudo permissions for example `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`

2). Add `amdgpu.backlight=0` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="..."`

2). Run `sudo update-grub`

3). Reboot

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/F-i-f/soft-brightness seems to be the only solution that works for (AM)OLED screens running on Wayland with Intel processor.

After installing soft-brightness, brightness gets adjusted via both Ubuntu control and keyboard.

Comment: +1 This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tried the solutions above, but none of them working on my Nvidia GPU/intel core i.7 CPU, Ubuntu 22.04 machine with wayland.
After updating the module `nvidia-dkms` the brightness control worked again:

```bash
sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-525
```

Comment: Few months ago the following helped me GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=vendor". However, last week it stopped working. Installing nvidia-dkms-525 package helped!

Comment: How did you know that `nvidia-dkms-525` was the correct package?

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'll still be in help. The best solution is to install a gnome shell extension called "Soft Brightness Plus", which allow you to change the screen brightness with both you keyboards and the slider.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Then you may go into the browse tab, find the extension and install it. Then return to the "Installed" tab, select the gear icon on the extension and turn on "Use backlight control"
Extension github page: https://github.com/jkitching/soft-brightness-plus.git

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 6.2.0-31-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
  Hardware Model: Vivobook_ASUSLaptop M7600QC_M7600QC

nvidia/525.125.06
dkms-2.8.7
```

On the contrary, I've **removed** the command `acpi_backlight=vendor` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and it helps.

Comment: Not in Ubuntu, but removing àcpi_backlight=vendor` from the kernel parameters solved the issue for me as well. Incidentally also with an `ideapad`. I noticed after that change and a reboot, that `/sys/class/backlight/ideapad` was changed to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight`. That is, the former directory no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the nvidia drivers.  Then I installed the nvidia drivers.  Then, hey presto, the sliders in brightness-control started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share that I tried a plethora of methods related to the grub configurations without any success, but I managed to solve this issue by simply updating the linux kernel. I had linux 22.04 LTS kernel 5.15 and updated it to 5.19.11-051911-generic.

My machine had 2 directories under /sys/class/backlight: amdgpu_bl0 and nvidia_0 and I was able to manually change the brightness value in the /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness with sudo. At first I thought it was because of the NVIDIA drivers but after uninstalling them the problem persisted. After the kernel update I no longer had the nvidia_0 folder in the /sys/class/backlight.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1254277)

Comment: Is there any link to how to update the linux kernel at all, please?

Comment: This actually works for me. Even though the Fn + Increase/Decrease Brightness on keyboard are still not working, I'm able to change the display brightness (laptop) by adjust these values. For me it's this path: sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness